# Specify a "where clause" when using a ReportViewer control and Report w/ Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, dataset, reportviewer

I am attempting to use the ReportViewer control with an Report (RDLC) file in local processing mode using an Oracle DB, and I cannot figure out how to specify a "where clause" in my query. I just want to return 1 row, as my report will be based on just 1 row from the query.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. I created a C# Windows Form Application (.NET 4.5) in Visual Studio 2013.
2. I added a DataSet named DataSet1.
3. I added a TableAdapter to the DataSet and created a connection to Oracle added a query. Here is the query "select * from Lei_Defect_Log". (It pulled
   in the column names.)
4. I added a Report named Report1 to the project.
5. On the "Report Data" window, I set the Dataset to the dataset I added
   above.
6. I dragged a few arbitrary columns from the Report Data window
   Dataset1 to the Report1 so I could verify it is working.
7. I added a ReportViewer named reportViewer1 to Form1 of the project. I set the
   Report of the reportViewer1 to Report1 created above.

Now, when I run the application, the report displays data from the query (must be the first row returned). But the table I am pulling from (Lei_Defect_Log) has thousands of rows, and I want to specify a where clause in my query to just return 1 specific row. (I want to do this in the code, and not prompt the user for it.)

I tried adding a where clause in the TableAdapter query as follows "select * from Lei_Defect_Log where RA_SN = :RA_SN_PARAM" which would be a correct query for Oracle, but I received the following error:

> The wizard detected the following problems when configuring the TableAdapter: "Fill":
>   Details:
>   Generated SELECT statement.
>     Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

It would allow me to click OK, but if I clicked OK my DataSet would not populate the column names. So no go.

I have been at this for many hours...and am stuck.

Everything I have seems to work, but I just need to be able to add a where clause to specify the row I need.

So how do I specify a where clause (in the code or designer, I don't want the user to be prompted for it) so my query returns just one row/record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

In the DataSet I right clicked on the TableAdapter and clicked "Configure" on the menu that opened. I added the parameter to the query like I did above and clicked Finish, then clicked OK and ignored the error. Then I right clicked on the text that says "FILL, GETDATA" and clicked Properties. Now go to the main Properties window and it should be the properties for the "Fill Query". Look for the Parameters property and open the Collection and set the DbType from Object to String..and it works!!!

See this [WEB PAGE](http://www.learningpenguin.net/myblog/2012/04/16/invalid-parameter-binding-error-when-using-oracle-odp-net-tableadapter/) for screenshots (I would have posted but need more SO cred to do so.)